# Conditional validation using single piece of code - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The code contains two functions. First one is defined as follows

```
scope.validateContactName = function() {
    scope.address.invalidName = false;
    if (!scope.address.name) {
      scope.address.invalidName = true;
    }
}
```

which is invoked by the function validateContactName();

Now i have another function

```
scope.validateContactPhone = function() {
    scope.address.invalidPhone = false;
    if (!scope.address.phone) {
      scope.address.invalidPhone = true;
    }
}
```

which is invoked by the function validateContactPhone();

**Instead of two functions, is there a way i can use a single function and do conditional validation?**

Something like

```
validateContactInfo('name');

function validateContactInfo(attr) {
   //do validation based on the attribute
   // There is only one single piece of code for both conditions
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe smth like this could work:

```
scope.validateField = function(field, errorField) {
  scope.address[errorField] = false;
  if (!scope.address[field]) {
    scope.address[errorField] = true;
  }
}
```

Or a shorter version:

```
scope.validateField = function(field, errorField) {
  scope.address[errorField] = !scope.address[field];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like this(ES6):

```html
scope.address = [
 {
  type: "phone",
  invalid: false
 },
 {
  type: "name",
  invalid: false
 }
];

const validate = type => {

 let data = scope.address.find(a => a.type === type);

 if(!data.type) {
  data.invalid = true;
 }
};


validate("phone");
validate("name");
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming contact information is used in a form to get input from the user. I would recommend to use [angular's own form validation](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-form-validation)

If it is not the case, here is a generic way of checking if values exists in a object. Which you can add in project''s utilities

```js
const contactInfo = {
name: 'My name',
phone: '123123123',
address: ''
}

function validateExistence(obj){
  const emptyKeys = [];
  for(let key in obj){
    if(!obj[key]) emptyKeys.push(key)
  }
  return emptyKeys
}

console.log(validateExistence(contactInfo));
```